# Image load in react project from an array of object(api)

Tags: reactjs

Images are in this directory public/images... and API file is in src/components/Basic directory.
I tried image:"../../pulic/images/imgName" and  image:"../../images/imgName"   too.

````
const Menu = [
  {
    id: 1,
    image: 'images/pasta.jpg',
    name: 'Pasta',
    category: 'Breakfast',
    price: '$10',
    description:
      'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe ad voluptatum',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    image: 'images/pizza.jpg',
    name: 'Pizza',
    category: 'Dinner',
    price: '$20',
    description:
      'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe ad voluptatum',
  },
];

export default Menu;
```[![directory][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMc37.png
````

Comment: Every other property is loading except the image property.

Comment: This posted file is in Basic component, images are in public/images/... and I am calling from src/components/Basic/Menu.js file...this posted code is in Menu.js